# Dropwizard: Sharing configuration between applications

Tags: java, configuration, dropwizard

Is there a architecturally correct way of sharing common configuration, such as Database and Messaging Provider connection details, across different Dropwizard applications?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about *architecurally correct*..... :-)

I would make a base Configuration class and stuff it in a common artifact that all dropwizard applications can depend on. (Assuming maven but should work with any build system.) In this base class you can have all configuration that is similar between applications. You will still need to add the actual values to a yml file per application. You don't want to have these values in your source code anyway so that is fine.